# Indexing Macros without a leading backslash in a dtx file

Tags: biblatex, indexing, package-writing

I'm documenting a file containing several `biblatex` bibmacros and booleans and would like to create an index via `\EnableCrossrefs`, but

```
% \begin{macro}{mybibmacro}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newbibmacro{mybibmacro}{}
%    \end{macro}
```

produces the entry

```
\mybibmacro
```

in the index and of course all further occurrences of `mybibmacro` in the code are ignored. Is there a way to avoid the leading backslash? Of course it would be perfect if future occurrences such as

```
\usebibmacro{mybibmacro}
```

would also be indexed under `mybibmacro`.

```
\newbool{mybool}
```

has exactly the same problem.

Combining this to a real example yields:

```
% \iffalse
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\EnableCrossrefs         
\CodelineIndex
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{test.dtx}
\end{document}
% \fi
%
% \DescribeEnv{mybibmacro}
% This is my bibmacro.
%
% \DescribeMacro{mybool}
% The boolean \verb|mybool| will determine, if \verb|mybibmacro| is executed.
% 
% \StopEventually{\PrintIndex}
%
% \begin{macro}{mybool}
% Here we define the boolean.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newbool{mybool}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
%
% \begin{environment}{mybibmacro}
% Here we define the bibmacro.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newbibmacro{mybibmacro}{}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{environment}
%
% Now the macro is executed depending on the status of \verb|mybool|. Ideally, both should be indexed as being used here.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\ifbool{mybool}{\usebibmacro{mybibmacro}}{}
%    \end{macrocode}
% 
% \Finale
```

Running this through latex and makeindex yields

[image: Compiled dtx file with index]

In the index `mybool` received a leading backslash and neither the usage of `mybool` nor of `mybibmacro` is indexed in line 3.

Also, the listing of `mybibmacro` under `environments` is slightly confusing, it might be good to get rid of that and of course optimal if one could add other categories in addition to environment (such as boolean, bibmacro etc.).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Probably you want to (ab)use or base something on `\begin{environment}` rather than `\begin{macro}` as that's not expecting the backslash form

---

First giving an extension working for environment usage as it is simpler, a more complete example in the next section.

here is an example modifying `doc` so that uses of `\begin{foo}` in macro code are not indexed as uses of `\begin` but as uses of the environment `foo` `\end` is automatically excluded from the index list.

**test2.sty**

```
\def\macro@finish{%
  \macro@namepart
\ifx\macro@namepart\xbegin
  \expandafter\macro@grabname
  \else  
\ifx\macro@namepart\xend
 \else
  \ifnot@excluded
     \edef\@tempa{\noexpand\SpecialIndex{\bslash\macro@namepart}}%
     \@tempa  \fi
  \fi\fi}

\def\xbegin{begin}
\def\xbegin{end}
\begingroup
\lccode`\(`\{
\lccode`\)`\}
\lowercase{\endgroup
\def\macro@grabname\fi(#1){%
(#1)%
\SpecialEnvIndex{#1}%
}
}
```

**test2.dtx**

```
% \iffalse
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{test2}
\EnableCrossrefs         
\CodelineIndex
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{test2.dtx}
\end{document}
% \fi
%
% \DescribeMacro{\mymacro}
% Some meaningful description.
% 
% \StopEventually{\PrintIndex}
%
% \begin{macro}{\mymacro}
% Here we define the macro.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand{\mymacro}{hello}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}

% \begin{environment}{myenv}
% Here we define the env.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newenvironment{myenv}{\par[[[}{]]]\par}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{environment}
%
% And here we use it.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\PackageInfo{test2}{\mymacro}
%    \end{macrocode}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\def\foo{\begin{myenv}kkk\end{myenv}}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \clearpage
%    \begin{macrocode}
\def\foobar{\begin{myenv}jjj\end{myenv}}
%    \end{macrocode}
% 
% \Finale
```

Process this with:

```
pdflatex test2.dtx
makeindex -s gind.ist test2
pdflatex test2.dtx
```

---

Note that `doc` doesn't care about how a macro is defined just what it looks like, `\begin{environment}` starts a definition but shows the macro without a backslash and indexes it under "environment" (standard doc). The addition here is that `begin{foo}` gets indexed as an environment use. So if you have a package with a definition form for bibmacro you and a use as `\newbibmacro` you would need to copy the definitions of environment from `doc`, including the above extension, to a set of macros that are the same but with `environment` changed to `bibmacro` and `\begin` changed to `\usebibmacro` and then again for `boolean` or any other non-backslash define/use categories that you need.

---

**Full BibLaTeX  version**

So, taking the above and then basically parameterising the environment code so it works for `environment` `bibbool` and `bibmacro` results in:
[image]

**testbool.dtx**

```
% \iffalse
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{test2}
\EnableCrossrefs         
\CodelineIndex
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{testbool.dtx}
\end{document}
% \fi
%
% \DescribeBibMacro{mybibmacro}
% This is my bibmacro.
%
% \DescribeBibBool{mybool}
% The boolean \verb|mybool| will determine, if \verb|mybibmacro| is executed.
%
% \DescribeMacro{\texmacro}
% Checking I haven't broken the original
% indexing macros  for \verb|\texmacro|.
%
% \StopEventually{\PrintIndex}
%
% \begin{bibbool}{mybool}
% Here we define the boolean.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newbool{mybool}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{bibbool}
%
% \begin{macro}{\texmacro}
% Here we define the boolean.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\def\texmacro{}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
%
% \begin{bibmacro}{mybibmacro}
% Here we define the bibmacro.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newbibmacro{mybibmacro}{}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{bibmacro}
%
% Now the macro is executed depending on the status of \verb|mybool|. Ideally, both should be indexed as being used here.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\ifbool{mybool}{\usebibmacro{mybibmacro}}{}
%    \end{macrocode}
% 
%    \begin{macrocode}
\texmacro
%    \end{macrocode}
% 
% \Finale
```

**test2.sty**

```
\def\bibmacro{\def\macro@type{bibmacro}\environment}
\let\endbibmacro\endenvironment


\def\bibbool{\def\macro@type{bibbool}\environment}
\let\endbibbool\endenvironment

\def\macro@type{environment}%% default

\def\macro@finish{%
  \macro@namepart
\ifx\macro@namepart\xbegin
  \def\macro@type{environment}%
\else\ifx\macro@namepart\xifbool
   \def\macro@type{bibbool}%
   \let\macro@namepart\xbegin
\else\ifx\macro@namepart\xusebibmacro
 \def\macro@type{bibmacro}%
 \let\macro@namepart\xbegin
\fi\fi\fi
\ifx\macro@namepart\xbegin
  \expandafter\macro@grabname
  \else  
\ifx\macro@namepart\xend
 \else
  \ifnot@excluded
     \edef\@tempa{\noexpand\SpecialIndex{\bslash\macro@namepart}}%
     \@tempa  \fi
  \fi\fi}

\def\xbegin{begin}
\def\xifbool{ifbool}
\def\xusebibmacro{usebibmacro}
\def\xend{end}
\begingroup
\lccode`\(`\{
\lccode`\)`\}
\lowercase{\endgroup
\def\macro@grabname\fi(#1){%
(#1)%
\SpecialxEnvUseIndex\macro@type{#1}%
}
}


\def\SpecialxEnvUseIndex#1{%
  \expandafter\SpecialxxEnvUseIndex\expandafter{#1}}

\def\SpecialxxEnvUseIndex#1#2{\@bsphack
    \special@index{#2\actualchar{\string\ttfamily\space#2}
           (#1)}%
    \special@index{#1s:\levelchar#2\actualchar{\string\ttfamily\space#2}}\@esphack}



\def\SpecialMainEnvIndex{%
   \expandafter\SpecialMainxEnvIndex\expandafter{\macro@type}}

\def\SpecialMainxEnvIndex#1#2{\@bsphack\special@index{%
                                      #2\actualchar
                                      {\string\ttfamily\space#2}
                                         (#1)%
                                      \encapchar main}%
    \special@index{#1s:\levelchar#2\actualchar{%
                   \string\ttfamily\space#2}\encapchar
           main}\@esphack}


\def\DescribeBibBool{%
\leavevmode\@bsphack\begingroup\MakePrivateLetters
\def\macro@type{bibbool}\begingroup\Describe@Env}

\def\DescribeBibMacro{%
\leavevmode\@bsphack\begingroup\MakePrivateLetters
\def\macro@type{bibmacro}\begingroup\Describe@Env}

\def\DescribeBibEnv{%
\leavevmode\@bsphack\begingroup\MakePrivateLetters
\def\macro@type{environment}\begingroup\Describe@Env}


\def\Describe@Env#1{\endgroup
              \marginpar{\raggedleft\PrintDescribeEnv{#1}}%
              \SpecialEnvIndex{#1}\endgroup\@esphack\ignorespaces}

\def\SpecialEnvIndex{%
   \expandafter\SpecialxEnvIndex\expandafter{\macro@type}}

\def\SpecialxEnvIndex#1#2{\@bsphack
    \index{#2\actualchar{\string\ttfamily\space#2}
           (#1)\encapchar usage}%
    \index{#1s:\levelchar#2\actualchar{\string\ttfamily\space#2}\encapchar
           usage}\@esphack}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my question providing an MWE that will hopefully clear things up.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much! I don't quite understand why the definitions get a separate line for their entry in the respective category, but it more than does the job!

Comment: sorry there was a `#1` that should be `#2` while writing to the index file, this is fixed and  test2.sty and the image updated

Comment: Why doesn't this work when I paste the content of the `sty` file into the header of the `dtx` file? I get the error `! Too many }'s.
l.45   \fi\fi}` (that's the last line of `\macro@finish`). It works with `input` so I really don't understand what could have happened ....

Comment: wel I think it's because of the doc package convention of guarding the top level document section with `%\iffalse`...`\fi` TeX's if-fi scanner needs to see balanced if-fi pairs but on the initial pass, the `doc` package hasn't been loaded so `\ifnot@excluded` isn't defined but the matching `\fi` is a primitive. There would be ways to avoid that but simplest is to keep it in a separate .sty :-)

Comment: actually I don't think that description is quite right but on one of the passes the if scanner is confused.